# Design recommendations for Image Converter Class

Tags: c++, templates, software-design

I am writing a small color space converter for a device, that records an image and displays it on a screen. The image is available as a planar 4:2:2 YUV image and needs to be converted into a 8 bit/channel RGB image. It is possible, that in the near future, the color space of the input image will change (maybe to a packed YUV image) as well as the target color space (maybe to a 16 bit/channel RGB image). Therefore, and as an exercise, I wanted to make my color converter easily adaptable. I decided to have a base image class, which provides a uniform interface for all image typesand use CRTP for static polymorphism as the image types will be known at compile time. The following simplified code shows the implementation of the image types:

```cpp
template <typename ImageType, typename ValueType>
class ImageBase {

public:
    using value_type = ValueType;
    const std::size_t cols;
    const std::size_t rows;
    value_type* data;

    std::size_t size() const {
        return static_cast<const ImageType*>(this)->sizeImpl();
    }

    template <typename T>
    T readAt(std::size_t index) {
        return static_cast<const ImageType*>(this)->template readAtImpl<T>(index);
    }

    virtual ~ImageBase(){
    }

protected:
    ImageBase(std::size_t cols, std::size_t rows): cols(cols), rows(rows), data(nullptr) {}
    ImageBase(std::size_t cols, std::size_t rows, value_type* data): cols(cols), rows(rows), data(data) {}

};

class RGB888: public ImageBase<RGB888, unsigned char> {

    friend ImageBase<RGB888, unsigned char>;
private:
    std::size_t sizeImpl() const{
        // Get size of type RGB888
    }

    template <typename T>
    T readAtImpl(std::size_t index) const {
        // Return a RGB struct for pixel(index) from raw data
    }

public:
    using value_type = unsigned char;
    RGB888(std::size_t cols, std::size_t rows): ImageBase(cols, rows) {}
    RGB888(std::size_t cols, std::size_t rows, unsigned char* data): ImageBase(cols, rows, data) {}
};

class YUV422_LOGIISP: public ImageBase<YUV422_LOGIISP, unsigned char> {

    friend ImageBase<YUV422_LOGIISP, unsigned char>;
private:
    std::size_t sizeImpl() const{
        // Get size of type YUV422_LOGIISP
    }

    template <typename T>
    T readAtImpl(std::size_t index) const {
        // Return a YUV struct for pixel(index) from raw data
    }

public:
    using value_type = unsigned char;
    YUV422_LOGIISP(std::size_t cols, std::size_t rows): ImageBase(cols, rows) {}
    YUV422_LOGIISP(std::size_t cols, std::size_t rows, unsigned char* data): ImageBase(cols, rows, data) {}

  template <typename T>
  RGB_t<T> yuv2rgb(double y, double u, double v) {
  // Convert a set of y, u, v to a single RGB pixel
  }
};
```

The conversion is implemented as follows:

```cpp
class ColorConverter {
public:

   template<typename SRC, typename DST>
   struct always_false : std::false_type {};

   template <class SRC, class DST>
   static void convertImage(SRC const& sourceImage, DST& destinationImage) {
       static_assert( always_false<SRC, DST>::value, "No conversion from SRC to DST" );
   }
};

template<>
void ColorConverter::convertImage<YUV422_LOGIISP, RGB888>(YUV422_LOGIISP const& src, RGB888& dst) {
// Do actual conversion
// Handle indices to access correct (y,u,v) values
// For every (y, u, v) set, call src.yuc2rgb to obtain a the rgb values
}
```

This way, in client code, I can convert between YUV and RGB like this:

```cpp
...
 // rgbImageData and yuvImageData are allocated somewhere else

RGB888 rgbImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, rgbImageData.data());
YUV422_LOGIISP yuvImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, yuvImageData.data());

ColorConverter::convertImage(yuvImage, rgbImage);
```

Now, the conversion from a (y,u,v) set to a (r,g,b) set is quite simple, the tedious part is extracting the YUV data into the correct (y,u,v) set as the data is interleaved and not located next to each other. I handle the (y,u,v) data access in the `ColorConverter::convertImageclass` but the actual conversion, from a set of (y,u,v) values to (r,g,b) values happens with a call to `src.yuv2rgb`.

At the moment, I have a dedicated conversion class, that only *helps* to convert, but the actual conversion happens in the image class. I am not happy with placing the yuv2rgb conversion function in the ColorConverter class and am not happy with placing it in the YUV422_LOGIISP class.

If I put the function into the ColorConverter class, I have detailed information in this class about a special case. On the other hand, if I place the function in the YUV422_LOGIISP class, the class also has the responsibility of converting and it breaks the uniform interface.

Most likely, this indicates a flawed design. No comes my question(s)...

How can I structure my code in a way that clearly separates concerns and minimizes dependencies? Should I look at using an `enum` for the conversion, similar to the way it is done in OpenCV?